# CMake and absolute header paths

Tags: c++, path, header, include, cmake

I'm trying to use CMake to build my C++ project and I have a problem in the header paths.

Since I'm using a lot of classes organized in several directories, all my include statements are with absolute paths (so no need to use "../../") but when try to make the CMake-generated Makefile it just doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to specify in CMakeLists.txt that all the includes are with absolute paths?

---

My output when trying to make

`~/multiboost/BanditsLS/GenericBanditAlgorithmLS.h:45:25: Utils/Utils.h: No such file or directory

~/multiboost/BanditsLS/GenericBanditAlgorithmLS.h:46:35: Utils/StreamTokenizer.h: No such file or directory`

My CMakeLists.txt file :

```
#The following command allows the use of the "file" command
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)  

#The declaration of the project
project(multiboost)  

#This allows recursive parsing of the source files
file(
    GLOB_RECURSE
    source_files
    *
    )  
list(REMOVE_ITEM source_files ./build/* )

#This indicates the target (the executable)  
add_executable(
    multiboost
    ${source_files} #EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL build/
    )
```

Comment: can you prvodie a small example (source/header/cmake)? also, absolute paths are generally a bad idea. The nicest way to do this is imo the way for instance boost does it: specify a single root that is in the include path from the compiler and start from there.

Comment: Yes exactly, this what I'm doing : Say I have a src/ dir which contains all the subdirs of the source as well as the main file. In all my include statements, I only have to specify the path from src/.
In my XCode project, it works fine but I didn't figure out yet how to make it in CMake. (Thanks for your answer ;o) )

Comment: yeah but we still need an example + more info ('it just doesn't work' is as cryptic as an error description can get, doesn't tell us anything at all)

Comment: Aside: Don't use a glob to build your filelist. Specify it by hand. This is important because it forces you to modify `CMakeLists.txt` when you add/remove a file, forcing `cmake` to re-run when you run `make`. If you don't do this, new or removed files will not get picked up, leading to breakage.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need something like this in CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET(BASEPATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${BASEPATH}")
```

Comment: Nice! I think this is exactly what was missing (the BASEPATH var)
Thanks fschmitt!

Answer (score 6):

set the correct include path: suppose your Utils directory is in /exp/appstat/benbou/multiboost, then cmake (well actually, gcc) has to know this:

```
include_directories( /exp/appstat/benbou/multiboost )
```

or it might be more convenient to pass this as an option which is passed on the command line:

```
include_directories( ${MyProjectRoot} )

cmake -DMyProjectRoot=/exp/appstat/benbou/multiboost
```

Comment: Thanks stjin. Btw, the CMake config file must be platform independent, it can be done with sone IF statements. Good luck!